# VisualSVN Server: post-commit hook failed. SVN: Unable to make name for 'D:\websites\mywebsite.com\tempfile

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

In VisualSVN Server, I am using a post-commit hook to move files from a directory in the Subversion repository to the proper directory on the file system.  I am getting the error shown below.

> Error:
>
> post-commit hook failed (exit code 1)
>   with output: svn: Unable to make name
>   for
>   'D:\websites\mywebsite.com\tempfile'

I am using TortoiseSVN to commit the files.  I am able to do this just fine with other projects, I don't see a file called tempfile in the directory structure of my local copy or repository, tried clean up and update commands with no success.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Weird. Have you read/tried this? http://blog.grovehillsoftware.com/2009/09/subversion-odd-problems-and-funny.html

Comment: Yeah, Following the post, I tried moving the entries file out of the .svn folder, running an update, then putting it back.  No luck.  I didn't see "incomplete" in the entries file like he did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out it was a **permissions** issue.  This is how I fixed it, so hopefully it will help others.

- Right-click the folder and select **Properties**
- Select the **Security** tab
- Add **Network Service**
- Check the boxes to allow **Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read, Write** permissions

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error, but from RubyMine (problem also could probably happen in Intellij IDEA).  The solution to me was to start RubyMine as administrator (right click on the icon and choose "Run as Administrator").  Problem went away.